# Commodity hardware related, i'm searching for a ILO, BMC, ALOM and in general IPMI alternate solution

Tags: remote-access, remote, electrical-power, keyboard-video-mouse, hardware

I'm searching for a composite solution to have the same features of an IPMI controller on commodity hardware independently from arch/model and without excessive device dependencies.

Essentially the problem can be divided in 2 parts:

1- remote control of basic input/output (can be solved with a small, compact, pure over IP KVM spider) please suggest products, companies, solutions about your experiences.

2- precise and forced of power remote control. 
- Remote powerup can be done by wake on lan in some cases, 
- force off need a ups control, 
- for acpi force off (10 sec pressing of power switch) it's necessary an "always powered and available device controlled by ip", that bypass poweron to simulate to press it.
- a complete solution can be an "always powered and available device controlled by ip", that bypass poweron to simulate to press it. and a bypass to input power cord, before power supply. simply a double bypass device.

please suggest products, companies, solutions about your experiences.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Product recommendations are, as general rule, not [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). The Google term for your second question is a switched/managed PDU, a smart power distribution unit that allows you remotely "yank the power cord" and plug it back in, which combined with a BIOS setting of start on return of AC power is a poor man's form of out-of-band management

Comment: Don't buy a server without out-of-band management. Just don't. You don't want to get into this situation to begin with. IPMI is just a baseline; things like ILO, DRAC, etc., are generally built on top of it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton true, about server hardware. i'm speaking about Commodity Hardware. Thanks. but it is not related.

Comment: @HBruijn Thanks for suggestion, any idea to simulate acpi force off?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest just buying better servers. You want this functionality built into the hardware platform, not as an add-on...

Yes, this could be done with switched PDUs (e.g. APC 8941), IP KVMs (i.e. Raritan rackmount or [Lantronix Spider](http://www.lantronix.com/it-management/kvm-over-ip/spider.html))... the higher-end IP KVMs can also perform virtual media functionality via USB dongle.

I've had to manage an environment with more than 1,000 servers and portable IP KVM switches. ***It sucked.*** As add-ons, these things are never smooth.

Your cheapest solution could be [serial console servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/347840/real-benefits-of-serial-console-servers-with-modern-server-hardware), coupled with switched PDUs and meticulous documentation. The benefit of the serial in this case would be that the per-machine cost is low (a modtap) and you can leverage Cat 5e cabling runs.

Comment: re: serial consoles - There's similar functionality in Windows via the Emergency Management Services feature: http://serverfault.com/questions/554298/windows-serial-console

Comment: @EvanAnderson Interesting. I knew something was possible on the Windows side... but in reality, people probably just prefer proper ILO/DRAC/IPMI, right?

Comment: Absolutely. The Windows interface has the neat feature that even in the face of a kernel panic the serial interface may still function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc784221(v=ws.10).aspx) via a kernel-mode driver. When I have a choice, though, I definitely prefer a dedicated OOB management card (and a switchable PDU, just to be sure).

Comment: Thanks Men, BUT. the answer it's not related to OS or server related only. Commodity Hardware, in general. Thanks.